# controller test_methods generating two errors intermittently

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following method is a refactoring placed in test_helper.rb

```
    def test_access(user, action)
      sign_in user
      get action
      assert_response :success
    end
```

in order to compact controller test statements

```
require "test_helper"

class CategorymajorsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    categorymajor = categorymajors(:one)
    @categorymajor_params = { categorymajor: { name: 'some name' } }
    @actions = [categorymajors_url, categorymajor_url(categorymajor)]
    @translator_actions = [new_categorymajor_url, edit_categorymajor_url(categorymajor)]
  end

  test "should get index" do
    @actions.each do |action|
      @internal_users.each do |user|
        test_access(user, action)
        assert_response :success
      end
    end
  end

  test "should get new edit" do
    @translator_actions.each do |action|
      test_access(@admin, action)
      assert_response :success
    end
  end
end
```

If the test is run per individual test

```
Finished in 0.831613s, 1.2025 runs/s, 14.4298 assertions/s.
1 runs, 12 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

but if the entire test controller is launched, two errors arise; the first everytime the method is called, the second once.

```
Error:
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest#test_access:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2)
    test/test_helper.rb:51:in `test_access'

[...]
Rails::Generators::TestCase#test_access:
RuntimeError: You need to configure your Rails::Generators::TestCase destination root.
    /Users/jerdvo/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/testing/behavior.rb:91:in `destination_root_is_set?'
    /Users/jerdvo/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:8:in `setup'
```

This makes little sense for two reasons:
a) two arguments are given, thus the call is somehow diverted from an expected path.
b) why would an individual test run (and pass) while a group, no.

The [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/TestCase.html) does not tell me where that file should be saved.

What is going on / error ?

Comment: please add a representative controller test file

Answer (score 0):

The reason for both errors is because the method in the test_helper.rb was not under `private`, explaining why `test_access` method was getting 0 arguments.

Proper:

```
private
    def test_access(user, action)
      sign_in user
      get action
      assert_response :success
    end
```

`Rails::Generators::TestCase` remains opaque to this reader.